# Lines of code that take on too much responsibility

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards, anti-patterns

Intuitively, I know that (in terms of a maintainable, understandable codebase) the following code is bad practice

```
var foo = fooFunc(barFunc(),wooFunc(chewFunc()));
```

and might be better stated as

```
var bar = barFunc();
var chew = chewFunc();
var woo = wooFunc(chew);
var foo = fooFunc(bar, woo);
```

This makes debugging easier, code more readable etc. etc...

Instead of personally spelling this out to co-developers, it might be better to lead them to an existing page that explains the perils of such a construct.

Is there an official term for this kind of anti-pattern?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: "Intuitively, I know... is bad practice" - eh? That kinda depends really. If `wooFunc` is an increment and `barFunc` and `chewFunc` are just getters, then your version is just clutter. The amount of flame generated by `is tertiary operator good or unreadable?`is beyond comprehension. This is just another version of it. Your company will have to decide on what balance of shorter code/clearer code you want to strike. If half your devs are entry level, clear is a definite yes. If your devs are used to read golfed code before bedtime - no point having them scroll through meaningless variables.

Comment: I hate the second; more code = less readable = less maintainable often times. Semantic density is something that needs to be balanced, your first example has too much meaning in a small space - it's too semantically dense, your second example is not dense enough; it takes too much reading to gain an insight into the semantic purpose of the code. It's intuitive to strike a balance of semantic density in english: You don't stretch a statement across as many words as possible, and you don't smush it into it's most compact form because neither is very understandable.

Comment: @Ordous It reminds me of the suggestion to break up long access chains onto multiple lines as a "solution" to Law of Demeter violations.

Comment: Keep in mind everyone that foo/bar examples don't always convey the same meaning.  In a real program, those intermediate variables usually can have much clearer, more locally-meaningful names than the functions, which tend to have more generic names because they are shared.  I agree, though, about readability if the variable names are only minor variations on the function names.

Answer (score 6):

The code form you want is called [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form) (ANF); it is not always more readable, but it might be more easily tranformable inside compilers, and is useful for precise [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (hence, many compilers are transforming the source code into some *intermediate* ANF). See also [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) form.

I don't believe that ANF is always more readable; on the contrary, coding with nested side-effect free function calls is often more easy to understand IMHO. But that is a matter of opinion, and of course depends upon the context. YMMV.

Of course, things may be different if some of the functions have significant (e.g. global) side effects, in particular because many programming languages do not specify an order of argument evaluation.

Comment: There are two main advantages to coding that way. You hit on the side effects: many languages have sequence points which help contain side effects. The other is debugging. Stepping through the single-line example in the question is awful. I would much rather have the expanded form while debugging.

Comment: On the other hand, stepping into fooFunc is hard in the first case with many debuggers.